# PHP pspell issue

Tags: php, string, integer

I am having issues with pspell when searching for numeric values I end up with a blank white page and a segmentation fault in the server logs:

```
[Fri Aug 21 10:08:43 2009] [notice] child pid 30064 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

When searching for a string everything works as expected. Below is the code I am using

```
$pspell_link = pspell_new("en", "british", "", "",(PSPELL_FAST|PSPELL_RUN_TOGETHER));
if (!pspell_check($pspell_link, $_GET['search'])) {
    $suggestions = pspell_suggest($pspell_link, $_GET['search']);
    if($suggestions) {
        ### do stuff
    }
}
```

I think it is pspell_suggest that is causing the error.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP code should never segfault, so this is an issue in your installation. Make sure you are up to date and try determining (by trail and error) what exactly triggers the segfault. If you are completely up to date and the segfault remains, consider posting a bug to http://bugs.php.net/

Comment: Thanks, got a hold of the people in charge on server they sorted out the config